# What are the constraints on the divisor argument of scipy.signal.deconvolve to ensure numerical stability?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numerical-stability, deconvolution

Here is my problem: I am going to process data coming from a system for which I will have a good idea of the impulse response. Having used Python for some basic scripting before, I am getting to know the scipy.signal.convolve and scipy.signal.deconvolve functions. In order to get some confidence in my final solution, I would like to understand their requirements and limitations.

I used the following test:
1. I built a basic signal made of two Gaussians.
2. I built a Gaussian impulse response.
3. I convolved my initial signal with this impulse response.
4. I deconvolved this convolved signal.
5. I compared this last signal to my initial one.
The outcome of this test was strongly dependent of how I defined my impulse response : either I managed to recover my initial signal, or the deconvolved signal was strongly diverging.

Here is the code:
I use python 3.4.2, numpy 1.8.2, and scipy 0.14.0.

```
import numpy as np  
from scipy import signal  


def gauss(x, amp = 1, mean = 0, sigma = 1):  
    return amp * np.exp(-(x - mean)**2 / (2 * sigma**2))  


step = 0.1  
x_os = np.arange(0, 200 + step, step)  
low = -5 # lower bound of the interval for the impulse response
up = 5  # upper bound of the interval for the impulse response
x_ir = np.arange(low, up + step, step)  

y_os1 = gauss(x_os, 160, 80, 5.0)  
y_os2 = gauss(x_os, 20, 20, 2.0)  
y_os = y_os1 + y_os2 # original signal  

y_ir = gauss(x_ir, 1 / (np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)), 0.0, 1.0) # impulse response 

y_c = signal.convolve(y_os, y_ir, 'full') # convoluted signal

y_d, _ = signal.deconvolve(y_c, y_ir) # deconvoluted signal
```

In the previous code, the divisor argument of scipy.signal.deconvolve is y_ir. I played with the parameters defining the interval on which y_ir is defined, e.g. [low, up, step]. To show you what puzzles me, let us take the three following sets :
1) `[-5, 5, 0.1]`,
2) `[-2, 2, 0.1]`,
3) and `[-2, 2, 0.5]` (note that step was not changed in the definition of y_os).

The following images show you the original signal along with the deconvolved signal for the three above-mentioned sets.
[Original signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkwQ6.png)
[Comparison of the deconvoluted signals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqxen.png)

Can anyone explain this behaviour? Are there any requirements on `divisor` that guarantee proper behaviour of this function?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have a similar problem of understanding `deconvolve`. I posted a new question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40615034/understanding-scipy-deconvolve) so if anyone can help there...